# Android Studio 4.1 Canary: Firebase Crashlytics breaks android project compilation

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics-android

**UPDATE:** This is fixed in [Crashlytics Gradle plugin version 2.0.0-beta04](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#crashlytics_gradle_plugin_v2-0-0-beta04).

Been trying to remove the soon to be deprecated Fabric Crashlytics SDK from the project I'm working on in favour of the new Firebase Crashlytics SDK. Unfortunately I'm having trouble compiling afterwards. I keep getting the following exception:

`Gradle sync failed: No such property: scope for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.ApplicationVariantData`

Here's the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: scope for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.ApplicationVariantData
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin.configureTaskDependencies(CrashlyticsPlugin.groovy:199)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin.configureUploadTask(CrashlyticsPlugin.groovy:187)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin.registerMappingFileTasks(CrashlyticsPlugin.groovy:142)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin$registerMappingFileTasks.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin.registerCrashlyticsTasks(CrashlyticsPlugin.groovy:101)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:483)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:77)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin$_apply_closure3.doCall(CrashlyticsPlugin.groovy:71)
    at org.gradle.util.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:154)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:105)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$WrappedConfigureAction.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:166)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1$1.run(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:100)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.reapply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$SetWithFewActions.execute(ImmutableActionSet.java:285)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:264)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:253)
    at com.android.build.gradle.AbstractAppExtension.addVariant(AbstractAppExtension.kt:64)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApiObjectFactory.create(ApiObjectFactory.java:118)
    ... 144 more
```

My build.gradle (app) file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.stanfy.spoon:spoon-gradle-plugin:1.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-android-gradle-plugin:$dokka_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.gladed.androidgitversion' version '0.4.10'
    id "com.vanniktech.android.junit.jacoco" version "0.15.0"
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.dokka-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply from: '../app/checkstyle.gradle'
apply from: '../app/ktlint.gradle'
apply from: '../app/androidgit.gradle'

androidExtensions.experimental = true

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionName androidGitVersion.name()
        versionCode androidGitVersion.code()
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.example.utils.CustomJUnit4TestRunner"

        // If set to 'true', enables the instrumentation class to start and stop profiling.
        // If set to false (default), profiling occurs the entire time the instrumentation
        // class is running.
        testHandleProfiling true

        // The following argument makes the Android Test Orchestrator run its
        // "pm clear" command after each test invocation. This command ensures
        // that the app's state is completely cleared between tests.
//        testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'

        // The following argument makes LeakCanary run when instrumentationtests run
//        testInstrumentationRunnerArgument "listener", "leakcanary.FailTestOnLeakRunListener"

        // Upon compilation, export our Room database schema into a JSON file. These represent
        // our database's schema history and are used for database migration testing
        // used by Room, to test migrations
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = [
                        "room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString(),
                        "room.incremental":"true"
                        // "room.expandProjection":"true"
                ]
            }
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled false
        }
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    ...

    // Crashlytics dependencies
    implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:$firebase_bom_version")
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
}
```

Anyone know the solution to this?

Comment: what does you build.gradle look like? Its going to be a problem in there

Comment: @tyczj I've added my build file. I also copied google-services.json into my app folder and added `classpath "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.0.0-beta03"` to my project build.gradle file.

Comment: Reply from Firebase Support: _We currently support only full releases of Android Gradle plugin in general. Nonetheless, I will share this information with the team._

Comment: Dropping the io.fabric.tools:gradle version from 1.31.2 to 1.31.0 seems to fix the problem. Decent solution though you'll lose some bugfixes, see the [changelog](https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin) to see if any of them are important for your project

Comment: @OlaBråten you saved my cat's life!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is now fixed in Crashlytics Gradle plugin version 2.0.0-beta04.

So upgrade the project `build.gradle` file with:

```
...
dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradle_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.0.0-beta04"
    }
...
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem seems to occur when using the new Android Studio 4.1 Canary.
The only workaround I've found is to go back to using the Android Studio 4.0 Beta, don't forget to also adjust the Android gradle plugin version to com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-beta02.

If you are playing around with Jetpack Compose and need 4.1 I guess you will have to disable Crashlytics until this is fixed either in Android Studio or the Crashlytics plugin.